# Extract from,to and value data from object created with bupaR package

Tags: r, bupar

I use the `bupaR` package to create a process map like below

```
library(bupaR)
patients %>%
    process_map(performance(mean, "days"))

perf<-patients %>%
    process_map(performance(mean, "days"))
```

what I would like to do now it to extract the data `from`, `to` and `value` as I can see them from the object that is created and pass them to a dataframe.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `edges <- attr(perf, "edges")`. This will give you a tibble from which you can extract the columns, run `head(edges)` to see them.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(perf))`.

Comment: patients are built in bupaR you can find it there

Comment: but yes 1st comment did it

Comment: @firmo23 can you post it as answer so that this question doesn't appear in "unanswered questions"?

Comment: I did also this is a follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744699/use-the-edges-dataframe-which-is-included-inside-a-process-map-object-to-subse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `edges <- attr(perf, "edges")`. This will give you a tibble from which you can extract the columns, run `head(edges)` to see them.